# How to shorten the namespace of custom view in xml in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I have a custom view defined deep in a package structure.

```
<com.android.notepad.example.customview.MyEditText
    id="@+id/note"
... />
```

It is not visually good to use the entire package name everywhere I want to use that view.
Can it be shortened?

We specify the namespace already in AndroidManifest.xml! (e.g com.android.notepad.example is already specified in AndroidManifest.xml file)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477981/using-custom-views-in-xml-without-using-fully-qualified-class-name