# Android XML Elements and Namespaces

Tags: android, xml, view, android-activity

Is it not possible to simplify the name of a custom element in an Activity XML file?

```
<com.library.CustomView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.library.customview"
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        app:newAttr="value" />
```

Say for example I have a CustomView control. Do I always have to put "com.library." in front of "CustomView" or is it possible to use xmlns:custom in a FrameLayout so that I don't need to?

This is what I would like to see (if possible):

```
<CustomView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.library.customview"
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        app:newAttr="value" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must specify the fully qualified name of the custom view class. The custom attribites belong to a different namespace. So you nee to have

```
 http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name].
```

That is why you have

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.library.customview"
```

It is necessary to specify fully qualified name of the custom view and hence

```
 <com.library.CustomView
```

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

The docs does not mention any other solution.

Edit:

There seems to be a workaround as mentioned in the below link. Notice comments on both answers. The authors feels there is a little overhead involved. So its left you to use the below although i recommend you to follow the above method mentioned in the docs.

[Using custom Views in XML without using fully-qualified class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477981/using-custom-views-in-xml-without-using-fully-qualified-class-name)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll stick with the fully qualified names. I guess it does make things clearer..  even if it isn't 'neat' :)